# Optimizing Mysql Query (in clause)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

```
SELECT 
    column1, 
    column2 
FROM `table` 
WHERE 
    column1 = '1 record' 
AND column2 IN ([Array of lacks record]) 
AND column3 IN ([thousands of records]))
```

Now its taking 18 seconds to run, can it be below 5 seconds.
Please suggest any alternative query for the same.

Comment: Do you have any indexes? Can you show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...`? Can you show the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`?

Comment: Indexing is done on both the columns.

Comment: there are 3 columns in your where statment! create one index for column1, column2 and column3 (in this order)

Comment: Do you mean you have several separate indexes or a combined index? Can you please post the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` in your question? This will help us a lot. Also can you please post the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` in your question? This will also help a lot.

Comment: Output of EXPLAIN: '1', 'SIMPLE', 'column 1', 'ref', 'index_column 3,index_column 1,index_column 2,some_id' '768', 'const', '398390', 'Using where'

Comment: @user1841413: Please include the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT` in your question. Don't post it as a comment, because that makes it impossible to read. Also please include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` in your question. Edit your question to add this information. Please try to format it so that it is readable.

Comment: Your query doesn't match with your table definition. In your query it says "column 1" and "column 2" but in your table definition no such columns exist. Could you fix that? At the moment your question is very vague. It's not possible to see if you have indexed the correct columns or not (but a quick glance at the output of EXPLAIN would suggest that you probably have not got the optimal indexes yet - it seems not to be using the multi-column index that you created).

Comment: Please post what Mark is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try putting the thousands of records for column 3 into a temp table and then join your existing table against the temp table. Saves using a massive IN clause.

Even better if the source of the contents of column 3 is a table which you can just do the join against.